# Plugin to count lines of code in PHPStorm

Tags: source-code, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm as my main IDE to development in PHP.

I was looking for any plugin to count lines of code (LOC) but I didn't find any. Someone knows a good option?

Requirements:

- Count all lines of code;
- Count lines ignoring comments and PHPDoc blocks;
- Count lines of a specific file;

Plugins for other JetBrain products which can be adapted to PHPstorm are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a plugin in the jet brains repo. Its called `PHPStats - SLOC Counter`. It does the SLOC analyses but in my option could have some better features, for example selecting files and via eg rightclick -> count SLOC get shown the SLOC for that selection.

Comment: Indeed, it could be better, but looks like the only option. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

There's another plugin named "Statistic", but it seems to be intended for Java:

> Shows project statistic. This plugin shows files sorted by their
>   extension along with size, line count LOC etc. User can select
>   (Project/Module/Package/File) scope using the 'Refresh on selection'
>   button. (This plugin requires Java 1.7)

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/4509-statistic